# Как суммировать списки в словаре?

Tags: python, python-3.x, списки, словари

Есть словарь, в котором ключ - это номер месяца, и у этого ключа есть список, в котором значение температуры каждого дня месяца и так 12 раз.

```
k={a:[0] for a in range(1, 13)}
for i in range(366):
  c,d=map(str, input().split())  ### Ввод в формате "dd.mm t" (t - это значение температуры, оно может быть как положительным, так и отрицательным, а также десятичным)
  c=int(c[3:5]) ### Мне не нужен день, мне нужен только месяц, поэтому я "отрезаю дни"
  d=float(d)
  k[c].append(d) ### В ключ номера месяца я записываю температуру d
print(sum(k.values())) ### Суммирую значения всего словаря
```

Как итог: ошибка "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list' on line 9". Вопрос, как быть? 
Входные данные:

```
01.05 10
02.05 15
03.05 -3
```

Как выглядит этот словарь:

```
{1: [0], 2: [0], 3: [0], 4: [0], 5: [0, 10.0, 15.0, -3.0], 
 6: [0], 7: [0], 8: [0], 9: [0], 10: [0], 11: [0], 12: [0]}
```

Что должно показать при выполнении `print(sum(k.values()))`: 25.0 (складывается сумма всех элементов списков словаря). Но увы, появляется ошибка

Comment: приведите пожалуйста в вопросе примеры входных данных (словарь) и то, что вы хотите получить на выходе

Comment: Почему `25`? Получится ведь `22` :) И еще, тут у вас излишество `c,d=map(str, input().split())` достаточно просто: `c, d = input().split()`

Comment: Ночью уже делал) А за наводку на излишество спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример подсчета в функциональном стиле:

```
d = {
    1: [0], 2: [0], 3: [0], 4: [0],
    5: [0, 10.0, 15.0, -3.0], 6: [0],
    7: [0], 8: [0], 9: [0],
    10: [0], 11: [0], 12: [0]
}
value = sum(map(sum, d.values()))
print(value)  # 22.0
```

---

Это может быть непонятным, поэтому опишу что происходит:

- `d.values()` возвращает список значений словаря, т.е. список списков: `[[0], [0], [0], [0], [0, 10.0, 15.0, -3.0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]`
- `map(sum, d.values())` применяет функцию `sum` к каждому элементу списка и сохраняет результат: `[0, 0, 0, 0, 22.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`
- А `sum(map(sum, d.values()))` суммирует итоговый список сумм

Answer (score 7):

По умолчанию функция `sum` суммирует к числу 0, полная форма выглядит так `sum(iterable [, start])`.
Параметр `start`, по умолчанию `0`, задает не только значение но и тип начального значения. Таким образом это можно использовать:

```
d = {1: [0], 2: [0], 3: [0], 4: [0], 5: [0, 10.0, 15.0, -3.0], 6: [0], 7: [0], 8: [0], 9: [0], 10: [0], 11: [0], 12: [0]}
print(sum(sum(d.values(), [])))
# 22
```

Answer (score 4):

Так как значениями словаря у вас являются списки, то нужно сначала просуммировать значения каждого списка, а потом посчитать общую сумму.

```
d = {
    1: [1,2,3], 
    2: [2,5,6]
}

values_sum = sum([sum(values_list) for values_list in d.values()])
print(values_sum)
# Результат - 19
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, примерно так и думал, но не знал, как реализовать

Comment: А ещё вопрос, а если мне нужно узнать сумму температуры за определённый месяц, то как это сделать?

Comment: `print(sum(k[5]))` - сумма температур в 5 месяце, например.